# Can 'mutex' of boost be used to for mutual exclusion among more than two threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex

Below is example from Boost for mutual exclusion between two threads:

```
mutex m;

thread1:
   m.lock();
  ... /* A */
  m.unlock();

thread2:
  m.lock();
  ... /* B */
  m.unlock();
```

My question is whether or not the above codes can be used to resolve conflict between more than two threads? In my opinion, it provides mutual exclusion between two threads only.

How to get mutual exclusion among more than two threads if the above doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, you can use it in as many threads as you want.

Comment: It's exactly purposed to do that, I don' t quite understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use it in as many threads as you want.

However, I'd recommend using `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard`:

```
std::mutex m;

//thread1:
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m); //<-- Automatically locks m upon construction of lg
            //... /* A */
    } //<- automatically unlocks m at the end of lg's life time

//thread2:
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m);
        //... /* B */
    }

//thread3:
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m);
            //... /* C */
    }
```